# How to run Logical Test in Tableau when one column has multiple rows

Tags: tableau-api

The first column only has one row while the second column has three rows that correspond to the first row of the first column. [For exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoE6Y.png), something like this.
Is there a way to run a logical test where if any of the values in the second column pass the test, I get a 1 and if none of the values in the second column pass the test, I get a 0.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The example you show is the tableau *visualisation* of a dataset, not the dataset. The actual data will have "Furniture" in *every* row with different values in the sub-category rows. So, simple logical formulae should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this, using LODs and simple boolean formula. Please give a more specific example of what you want to do and you can have a formula that'll do it.